# transform data frame using tidyr

Tags: r, tidyr

I have this:

```
library(tidyr)

haves <- data.frame(
        model1_prediction = c(1, 2)
        , model2_prediction = c(3, 4)
        , model3_prediction = c(5, 6)
        , actuals = c(99.1, 99.2)
      )

model1_prediction model2_prediction model3_prediction actuals                 
1                 3                 5    99.1
2                 4                 6    99.2
```

I would like to obtain this:

```
wants <- data.frame(
        long = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
        , actuals = c(99.1, 99.2, 99.1, 99.2, 99.1, 99.2)
     )

wants

long actuals
1    99.1
2    99.2
3    99.1
4    99.2
5    99.1
6    99.2
```

My long wounded working attempt is the following but wonder if there is a better way? Thanks.

```
t1 <- haves %>%
    select(
        model1_prediction
        , model2_prediction
        , model3_prediction
    ) %>%
    mutate(
        id = row_number()
    ) %>%
    gather(
       key, long, -id
    )
t1
t2 <- haves %>%
    select(
        actuals
    ) %>%
    mutate(
        id = row_number()
    ) %>%
    gather(
       key, actuals, - id
    )
t2
my_longwounded_wants <- t1 %>%
    inner_join(t2, by = c("id" = "id")) %>%
    select(
        long
        , actuals
    )
my_longwounded_wants
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tidyr)

haves %>% pivot_longer(cols = -actuals) %>% arrange(value) %>% select(value,actuals)
```

Output:

```
  value actuals
1     1    99.1
2     2    99.2
3     3    99.1
4     4    99.2
5     5    99.1
6     6    99.2
```

Comment: Am I right in assuming that the arrange is redundant?

Comment: @cs0815 It depends of how you want your final output. For sure you can avoid it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set `names_to = NULL` in `pivot_longer()` to drop the column which records original column names. That can save you the use of `select()` to make the code more concise.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

haves %>%
  pivot_longer(-actuals, names_to = NULL) %>%
  arrange(value)

# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   actuals value
#     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    99.1     1
# 2    99.2     2
# 3    99.1     3
# 4    99.2     4
# 5    99.1     5
# 6    99.2     6
```